# node.js + socket.io: auction website development

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, node-redis, node-cluster

I am currently working on an auction script using node.js and socket.io.But site was developed by using PHP & MySQL. Here I'm using node.js + socket.io for auction bidding process only. The site will have 500-1000 logged in users viewing a single page during the auction. Only one item will be on auction and it will be sold at one day once.

I will be broadcasting(emitting) a countdown timer to all of the users from the server to the client. On the server side I will be using setInterval(),recursive setTimeout() of 1 second to countdown to the auction end time. Apart from this the only other message being sent across will be the current bid being passed from a single client to the server then broadcast to all. This way to do be a reliable? And will it be able to handle the usage on the server?. Here I've tested with 500 users means in browsers getting hanging the timer.

### Server.js

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var app = require('express')();
//var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var socket = require('socket.io');
var redis = require('redis');
var redisAdapter = require('socket.io-redis');
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('keys/e1317_0f2c9_71565598d419e37e376ccef5c2827113.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('certs/e1317_0f2c9_1468152279_2dc46c1f2cc135a.crt'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync('cabundles/90490a5c829d2aca24f22b5820864c6e_1935558000.cabundle')
};

//var server = http.createServer( app );
var server = https.createServer(options, app);
var io = socket.listen(server);

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var workers = process.env.WORKERS || require('os').cpus().length;

var redisUrl = process.env.REDISTOGO_URL || 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379';
var redisOptions = require('parse-redis-url')(redis).parse(redisUrl);
var pub = redis.createClient(redisOptions.port, redisOptions.host, {
    detect_buffers: true,
    return_buffers: true,
    auth_pass: redisOptions.password
});
var sub = redis.createClient(redisOptions.port, redisOptions.host, {
    detect_buffers: true,
    return_buffers: true,
    auth_pass: redisOptions.password
});

io.adapter(redisAdapter({
    pubClient: pub,
    subClient: sub
}));

console.log('Redis adapter started with url: ' + redisUrl);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(client) {
    //console.log('first');
    client.on('nauction', function(data) {
        io.sockets.emit('nauction', data);
    });
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    //console.log('in');
    console.log('connected client count:' + io.sockets.sockets.length);
    var recursive = function() {
        //console.log("It has been one second!");
        if (io.sockets.sockets.length > 0) {
            request('https://www.example.com/file.php', function(error, response, body) {
                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                    data = JSON.parse(body);
                    socket.volatile.emit('auction_data', {
                        'auction_data': data
                    });
                    //console.log(data);
                } else {
                    //console.log('else');
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        } //else{
        //console.log('No clients connected now');
        //}
        setTimeout(recursive, 1000);
    }
    recursive();
    socket.on("disconnect", function() {
        console.log('clear interval')
            //clearInterval(interval);
        clearTimeout(recursive);
    });
});

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    console.log('start cluster with %s workers', workers - 1);
    workers--;
    for (var i = 0; i < workers; ++i) {
        var worker = cluster.fork();
        console.log('worker %s started.', worker.process.pid);
    }

    cluster.on('death', function(worker) {
        console.log('worker %s died. restart...', worker.process.pid);
    });
} else {
    start();
}

function start() {
    server.listen(port, function() {
        console.log('listening on *:' + port);
    });
}
```

### Client.js

```
socket.on('auction_data', function(auction_details) {
    //console.log(auction_details);
    $.each(auction_details, function(keys, values) {
        //countdwon formation
        var tm, days, hrs, mins, secs;
        days = value.auction_data.time.days;
        if (value.auction_data.time.hours < 10) {
            hrs = ("0" + value.auction_data.time.hours);
        } else {
            hrs = value.auction_data.time.hours;
        }
        if (value.auction_data.time.mins < 10) {
            mins = ("0" + value.auction_data.time.mins);
        } else {
            mins = value.auction_data.time.mins;
        }
        if (value.auction_data.time.secs < 10) {
            secs = ("0" + value.auction_data.time.secs);
        } else {
            secs = value.auction_data.time.secs;
        }
        if (days == 0) {
            tm = '' + hrs + '' + '' + mins + '' + '' + secs + '';
        } else {
            tm = '' + days + '' + '' + hrs + '' + '' + mins + '' + '' + secs + '';
        }
        $('#auction_' + value.auction_data.product_id + " .countdown").html(tm);
    });
});
```

I'm waiting for your answers to fix the browser hanging problem.

Comment: There is no valid metric present to give you a `yes` or `no` answer. There's just too many questions that haven't even been asked, from the hardware to actual peak time connections, bandwith required etc. It's just not realistic to ask these kinds of questions without collecting all the information first. If you need an accurate answer, hire a company to perform an audit. If you can't afford it, then just try to measure yourself.  You will **not** get a proper answer on SO, no matter how much you wanted to get one.

Comment: As a NodeJS Developer myself, i can tell you it is better to create Modules. Objects with Prototypes. It increases the readability of you code extremely!

Comment: @Mijago, Thanks for suggestion I'll try to use modules also and more things. Because I;m currently learning the node.js and working on the project.

Comment: @mjh, I'm not get your point regarding the valid metrics

Comment: What's unclear? That you didn't provide any usable numbers? You didn't provide a single number (metric) that would help us tell you what you want to hear. Insufficient information present.

Comment: @sankarmuniyappa Hope you don't mind me asking but why are you switching to node for the bidding aspect ?

Answer (score 5):

**First Question:** *Is This way to do be a reliable?*

Sending the time every Second to EVERY client is not necessary. Simply send them the time at their first visit and use a local timer (at their local page) to reduce the time every second.

You also need to check for server-time on every bid (more secure).

If this is not "secure" enough for you, send the time with the changing bid. You only have to send the actual Bid, when it changed (using Broadcast) or when the user joins the site (just send it to him).

**Second Question:** *And will it be able to handle the usage on the server?*

Yes and No.

If your Sever is good enough (every 5$ server with endless traffic would fit),
you should not get in trouble. Only, if your script is very very bad and seeded with Memory Leaks.

**Now a few tips:**

- Never trust the user input - parse it before you use it!
- Recalculate everything you get from the client on the Server.
- Send the Client only what he needs. He does not need information about stuff that he does not use.

If this was the answer you hoped for, please select the green arrow on the left.
If not, write a comment here and I will give more tips.

Comment: Hi Mijago, Before using cluster process site handles 300-400 users properly timer working and getting more than 400 users website get hanging. After changing process with cluster & redis pub sub not handling 5 users properly. I don't know how local timer will works and it needs work based on specific country timezone.

Comment: No it does not require timezone handling, you give them the seconds-to-end-of-auction and simply count down with a timer to zero.

Comment: Also here I'm explaining the process of bidding with my website in timer is less than 15 seconds if user placing the bid means need to reset timer with 15 seconds and auction price & history details to all users(who are all opened the website). And also if timer reaches 0 means need to close the bid for that auction how it will done for this process?

Comment: Without using the cluster process server was handling 400-500 users only with website if get more than 500 users website get hanging. But after adding cluster,redis methods with server.js and then website 10 users only handling & timer countdown not working properly. If we use cluster process means it with live server creating the 10 child process so this cause the issue?